# Insert data from one table to another table in chunks - MySQL

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, bulk

I have been trying to load data from one table that has 100 million + rows into a new table based on a filter. I have tried to load using the procedure below but for some reason it just sits there with no result or activity in processlist.

I have been trying to insert data based on updated date but end up either inserting the same data each time running into a PK violation or no update.

Please advise what's the best way to load this data into a new table. Thanks

```
USE `mydb`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `insert_data`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `ods`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_data` ()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE limitSize INT DEFAULT 2000;
DECLARE maxupdate datetime;

SET maxupdate = (SELECT MAX(updated) FROM test_data);

WHILE i <= maxId DO
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test_arc
SELECT * FROM test_data 
WHERE check_time>='2022-02-05' and updated> i
ORDER BY updated ASC
LIMIT limitSize;
COMMIT;
SET i = i + limitSize;
END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER;

--My Tables:
--Actual Table
 CREATE TABLE test_data (
 UNIQUE_ID bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 DEVICE_NAME varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PARAMETER_NAME varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
 GMT_OFFSET varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 CHECK_TIME datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
 OUTPUT_DATA text NOT NULL,
 PERF_DATA text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (UNIQUE_ID)
 );

 --Archive Table
CREATE TABLE test_arc (
UNIQUE_ID bigint(11) NOT NULL,
DEVICE_NAME varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PARAMETER_NAME varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
GMT_OFFSET varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
CHECK_TIME datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
OUTPUT_DATA text NOT NULL,
PERF_DATA text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (UNIQUE_ID)
```

);

Comment: You query maxupdate, but then test for the undefined maxid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction you don't really that is why i removed it, the rest ist controlled by LIMIT and OFFSET which you need to do such a partial updates in block

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test_arc (id int,check_time datetime, updated datetime)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test_data (id int,check_time datetime, updated Datetime)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test_data VALUES (1,NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY),(2,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY)
> ,(3,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY),(4,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY)
> ,(5,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY),
> (6,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY),(7,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY)
> ,(8,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY)
> ,(9,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY),(10,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY,NOW()- INTERVAL 1 DAY)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test_data
> ```

> ```
> id | check_time          | updated            
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------
>  1 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  2 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  3 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  4 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  5 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  6 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  7 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  8 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
>  9 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
> 10 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_data` ()
> BEGIN
> DECLARE i BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
> DECLARE limitSize INT DEFAULT 5;
> DECLARE maxnumber BIGINT;
>
> SET maxnumber = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_data) + 1;
>
> WHILE i <= maxnumber DO
>      INSERT INTO test_arc
>          SELECT id ,check_time, NOW() FROM test_data 
>          WHERE check_time>='2022-02-05'
>          ORDER BY updated ASC
>          LIMIT i, limitSize
>      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id =VALUES(id), check_time=VALUES(check_time),updated  = Values(updated );   SET i = i + limitSize;
> END WHILE;
> END
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CALL insert_data();
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test_arc
> ```
>
> ```
> id | check_time          | updated            
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------
>  1 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  2 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  3 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  4 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  5 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  6 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  7 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  8 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
>  9 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
> 10 | 2022-02-12 18:27:12 | 2022-02-13 18:27:12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a57e3802d81a17796d8f349e93bc2ec)*

Comment: Thank You, this helped me get started but I run into same issues where I have the same column being reinserted causing PK violations. If I alter the script to load based on date such as load data for 01st Jan 2021 then 02nd Jan 2022, the Procedure does nothing but just shows as executing. 

Basically this is my table which has data for over 1 year, I want to insert data into a new table only or past 90 days & data insert needs to be chunks as it is huge.  I have updated my table create statement. Please suggest the best way to insert data by day, commit & get data for next day.  Thanks

Comment: For the problem, withthe duplicates i added a little code line that hanles that which you have to adept.

Comment: Thank You, I have tested in DB Fiddle & will test on my DB shortly.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1a536f2bb4fe67d1092537864972e1ba